# Apache fop: generates blank pdf-output

Tags: xslt, pdf, apache-fop

I'm trying to generate a PDF using Apache Fop and Java, but the produced Pdf is always a blank page.
It's all nested in a Web-Application, the Sever is glassfish.

Does someone hav a suggestion?

Here's my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
           <fo:layout-master-set>
               <fo:simple-page-master master-name="DealerOverview">
                   <fo:region-body margin-top="4cm" margin-bottom="2cm" />
                   <fo:region-before extent="3.5" />
                   <fo:region-after extent="3.5" />
               </fo:simple-page-master>
           </fo:layout-master-set>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="DealerOverview" />
          </fo:root>
      </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="DealerOverview">
       <fo:page-sequence master-reference="DealerOverview">
           <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
               <fo:block>
                   <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
                       <fo:table-body>
                           <fo:table-row>
                               <fo:table-cell text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                   <fo:block>Brand</fo:block>
                               </fo:table-cell>
                               <fo:table-cell text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                   <fo:block>TargetYear</fo:block>
                               </fo:table-cell>
                               <fo:table-cell text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                   <fo:block>TargetPrevYear</fo:block>
                               </fo:table-cell>
                           </fo:table-row> 
                           <xsl:for-each select="DealerOverview/Brands/Brand">
                                   <fo:table-row>
                                       <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                           <fo:block>
                                               <xsl:value-of select="BrandId" />
                                           </fo:block>
                                       </fo:table-cell>
                                       <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                           <fo:block>
                                               <xsl:value-of select="TargetYear" />
                                           </fo:block>
                                       </fo:table-cell>
                                       <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                           <fo:block>
                                               <xsl:value-of select="TargetPrevYear" />
                                           </fo:block>
                                       </fo:table-cell>
                                   </fo:table-row>
                               </xsl:for-each>   
                       </fo:table-body>
                   </fo:table>
               </fo:block>
           </fo:flow>
       </fo:page-sequence>
       </xsl:template>
        <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And an Example-XML-File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DealerOverview>
    <DealerDetails>
        <Version>testForDealer</Version>
        <Date>Oct, 1, 2013</Date>
        <State>Released to Dealer</State>
        <Dealer>Ungeheuer Automobile GmBH</Dealer>
        <BrandOverview>All</BrandOverview>
    </DealerDetails>
    <Brands>
        <Brand id="BM">
            <BrandId>BM</BrandId>
            <TargetYear>500</TargetYear>
            <TargetPrevYear>1000</TargetPrevYear>
        </Brand>
    </Brands>
</DealerOverview>
```

**EDIT:**
The Java-code which should generate the pdf...

```
public void createPdfWithFop(File xmlString) throws IOException {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) context.getExternalContext().getContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        pathToXsl = servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/reporting/PrintDealersOverview.xsl");

        File xslFile = new File(pathToXsl);
        String tempString = FileUtils.readFileToString(xmlString);
        System.out.println("Das XML-File in der Fop: " + tempString + "  ende");
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(xmlString);
        StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(xslFile);

        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
        FOUserAgent userAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(transformSource);
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, outStream);
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

            transformer.transform(source, res);

            byte[] pdfBytes = outStream.toByteArray();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"DealersOverview.pdf\"");
            response.getOutputStream().write(pdfBytes);
//            response.getOutputStream().flush();

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FOPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

**Second EDIT:**

I found out, that there's something wrong with my outputStream. 
I want to show a save-as-dialog in order to download the generated file from my web application.
I don't see, whats wrong with my output...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you get a blank page because running the above transformation does produce some output for me.

However, I did notice that your for-each is not correct. Your select is looking for `DealerOverview/Brands/Brand` but because you are already in the `DealerOverview` template that select is looking for an element at this location `DealerOverview/DealerOverview/Brands/Brand` which doesn't exist. So if you remove the `DealerOverview` from the select you do get additional information in your output.

Comment: thanks for your hints, but that wasn't the solution. Perhaps something is wrong with my java code...